# Perdida de valores inroducidos en BBDD

Tags: java, hibernate

no hace mucho formulé una pregunta sobre la perdida de registros introducidos en BBDD Oracle.
Un compañero me dió una pista y se hizo que a la hora de registrar los datos pase lo que pase que los guarde.
Lo hacemos mediante Hibernate y lo que sucede es que al guardar los registros, los ves en pantalla pero al refrescar ya no aparacen, se eliminan de la BBDD.
¿Alguna idea de lo que puede estar ocuerriendo?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Has hecho `COMMIT`?

Comment: Sin un [mcve] es casi imposible intentar proporcionar una respuesta.

Comment: Sí, e incluso un compañero utilizó .flush(); para forzar el gusrdado y tenemos el mismo problema.

Comment: Como bien dices SJuan76 tienes toda la razón, que sin ejemplo es difícil. Lo peor de todo es que sabemos con seguridad, a parte del las quejas del cliente, por un compañero que lo vió. Pero en nuestro entorno de desarrollo no replicamos el error, incluso en entorno de pruebas antes de subir a producción tampoco.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que "se eliminan de la BBDD" y que simplemente no se llegaron a guardar nunca en ella? ¿Podrías comprobarlo? Quizá el problema esté en la inserción.

Comment: Ahora sí que me acabas de dejar en duda, como en entorno de desarrollo y debugando vemos que funciona correctamente dabamos por supuesto que sí guarda, también una vez introducidos según el compañero y el cliente aparecen en el listado :(